# How to know if user has purchased a subscription before (but the subscription is no longer active)?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I know that we can query Google Play to know if a user currently has an active subscription, however, will it be possible to know if a user has previously purchased a subscription and that subscription has now ended?

Ie:
User buys "Infinite Gas" subscription for 1 month in January (not auto renew). When the user access the app in February, the "Infinite Gas" subscription has ended, however, is it possible to query Google Play to know that the user has bought the "Infinite Gas" subscription before?